# Find value of $\sin x-\frac{1}{\cot x}$

Tags: trigonometry, polynomials, roots, nested-radicals, quartics

If $\sin x+\frac{1}{\cot x}=3$, calculate the value of $\sin x-\frac{1}{\cot x}$

---

Please kindly help me

---

Let $\sin x -\frac{1}{\cot x}=t$
Then, $$\sin x= \frac{3+t}{2}, \cot x= \frac{2}{3-t}$$
By using $$1+\cot ^2x= \frac{1}{\sin^2 x}$$
Then, the equation $$t^4-18t^2+48t+81=0$$

Comment: This question is phrased in a strange way: just observe $\frac{1}{\cot x} = \frac{1}{1/\tan x} = \tan x$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\tan{x}=y$.

Thus, $$\sin{x}+y=3,$$ which gives
$$\sin^2x=(3-y)^2$$ or
$$\frac{y^2}{1+y^2}=(3-y)^2$$ or
$$y^4-6y^3+9y^2-6y+9=0$$ or for any real $k$
$$(y^2-3y+k)^2-(2ky^2-6(k-1)y+k^2-9)=0.$$
Now, we'll choose a value of $k$, for which $k>0$ and $$2ky^2-6(k-1)y+k^2-9=(ay+b)^2,$$
for which we need $$9(k-1)^2-2k(k^2-9)=0$$ or
$$2k^3-9k^2-9=0,$$ which by the Cardano's formula gives:
$$k=\frac{3+3\sqrt[3]3+\sqrt[3]9}{2}$$ and we obtain:
$$\left(y^2-3y+\frac{3+3\sqrt[3]3+\sqrt[3]9}{2}\right)^2-(3+3\sqrt[3]3+\sqrt[3]9)\left(y-\frac{3+3\sqrt[3]3-\sqrt[3]9}{2}\right)^2=0,$$
which gives two quadratic equations.

One of them has no real roots.

The second gives two real roots:
$$\frac{\sqrt[3]3}{2}\left(\sqrt[3]9+\sqrt{1+\sqrt[3]3+\sqrt[3]9}-\sqrt{2\sqrt{2(\sqrt[3]3-1)}-(\sqrt[3]3-1)^2}\right)$$ and
$$\frac{\sqrt[3]3}{2}\left(\sqrt[3]9+\sqrt{1+\sqrt[3]3+\sqrt[3]9}+\sqrt{2\sqrt{2(\sqrt[3]3-1)}-(\sqrt[3]3-1)^2}\right)$$ and we obtain:
$$\sin{x}-\tan{x}=3-2y=\sqrt[3]3\left(-\sqrt{1+\sqrt[3]3+\sqrt[3]9}+\sqrt{2\sqrt{2(\sqrt[3]3-1)}-(\sqrt[3]3-1)^2}\right)$$ or $$\sin{x}-\tan{x}=-\sqrt[3]3\left(\sqrt{1+\sqrt[3]3+\sqrt[3]9}+\sqrt{2\sqrt{2(\sqrt[3]3-1)}-(\sqrt[3]3-1)^2}\right).$$

Comment: Thank so much on your answering

Comment: @Petter Green  I added something. See now. You are welcome!

Comment: Yeah I saw .Note

Comment: Could you tell me about your way let and solve the 4th degrees equation? Do you have more explain about this way ? I want to see the lesson about this method ?

Comment: @Petter Green  It's just a standard substitution $y^2+1=2ty$, We have $y^4+1=(y^2+1)^2-2y^2=y^2(4t^2-2)$, $y^3+y=y(y^2+1)=2y^2t.$

Comment: not like this. But I want to know that how could I know the form how to let $y^2+1=2ty$?

Comment: So it works for any polynomial and lets in the same form ?

Comment: do you have any document about this way share to me ?

Comment: @Petter Green  It works for any polynomial of an even degree $n$ as the following. $a_0x^n+a_1x^{n-1}+...+a_1x+a_0.$ For example $x^6-x^5+3x^4-x^3+3x^2-x+1=(8t^3-6t)x^3-x(4t^2-2)x^2+3x^2\cdot2t-x^3=(8t^3-4t^2+1)x^3.$

Comment: @Petter Green I fixed a typo.

Comment: Really thank so much. I will find out about this method more.

Comment: please tell me how to solve the equation $y^4-6y^3+9y^2-6y+9=0$. By the way, when I expand I saw this form.

Comment: @Petter Green  Wait please. I'll show. It was my big mistake. I'll show a full solution.

Comment: Ok noted. I will wait.

Comment: @Petter Green  I posted. Now, we see that probably there is a mistake in your given. But I wrote a full answer, as I said.

Comment: Could you tell me about this point ?
$9(k-1)^2-2k(k^2-9)=0$
Why ?

Comment: @Petter Green Because we want that would be $2ky^2-6(k-1)y+k^2-9=(ay+b)^2$, for which we need $\Delta=0$. By the way, I checked that the numbers, which I got they are roots of your equation: $t^4-18t^2+48t+81=0.$

Comment: Ok thank so much. Now I knew

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

$\sin x+\dfrac1{\cot x}=3$

Let $\sin x-\dfrac1{\cot x}=y$

Solve for $\sin x, \dfrac1{\cot x}$

Now use $$\dfrac1{\sin^2x}-\cot^2x=1$$